# Error occur when trying to save data to SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have pass the data from `Project1.java` to `Claims.java` and named them to `name` and `result`. They can show on `c.setText`. But when I want to save them in SQLite database, app crashed.

**Claims.java**

```
  String result;
    String name;
    fk = bundle.getLong("ab");

         @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                int button = data.getIntExtra("k1", 0);

                if (button == 1) {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                        case 0:
                            result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                            name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                             as=Long.parseLong(result);
                            c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                             result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                            name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                             as=Long.parseLong(result);
                            c.setText("            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                            break;

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    if ((name != null && name.trim().length() > 0) && (result != null && result.trim().length() > 0)) {
                        SB.insertStaffBenefit(name, result, fk);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            });
```

> 11-04 17:09:40.876  20272-20272/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 20272
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.project.project.Claims$7.onClick(Claims.java:153)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)

After did like what @Mohit suggested, now I get another error

> 11-05 01:45:01.612    2505-2505/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 2505
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
>   com.example.project.project.API.StaffAPI.insertStaffBenefit(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, long)' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.project.project.Claims$7.onClick(Claims.java:153)

Comment: try initial your `name` and `result` because they might pointing toward `null` value when they are created;

Comment: @Mohit how to initial?

Comment: Refer [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: no..I tried but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String result = "";
String name = "";
```

Comment: Please provide some centext - why does this address the question?

Comment: Another issue is because  I forgot to initialize SB